# how to get the right Element from recyclerView

Tags: java, android

We are currently developing an Android application but we're walking into a problem.

We have a recyclerView which get filled with CardView's based on database results.
Inside the CardView we have a button.

Now we try to create a onclick effect on the button (this works).

But when we onClick the button in the cardView we want the code to return the specefic ID for that cardView.

We tried to use

```
getParent()
```

but it returns the same cardview even if we press a button on another cardView. Is this possible without creating an onClick on the recyclerView itself?

We want the unique ID of the cardview

Edit:

We want the button on the card to extract the information on that card

Fragment:

```
    package info.androidhive.materialnavbar.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import info.androidhive.materialnavbar.Activity.MainActivity;
import info.androidhive.materialnavbar.CardItem;
import info.androidhive.materialnavbar.R;
import info.androidhive.materialnavbar.ViewAdapters.RVAdapter;

/**
 * Created by bart on 10-6-2015
 * 2015 - 06
 * Superclass for all Information Fragments
 * Class handles the inflation of the RecyclerView and the XML files
 */

public class InformationFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RVAdapter mRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static List<CardItem> CardEntry;
    private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
    public static boolean refresh = false;



    //haalt list leeg
    public void refreshFragment(){
            // zet fragment op null
            Fragment frg = null;
            frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(2131296339);
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(frg);
            ft.attach(frg);
            ft.commit();
    }

    // recycler list
    public List<CardItem> getCardData(int type) {
        CardEntry = new ArrayList<>();
        // tijdelijk knop voor testing
        int reporticon = R.drawable.reporttemp;
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                // Vull kaartjes met volgende items :
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Today", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Today", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Today", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Today", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Today", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Today", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                //workaround
                //zet case type om naar cardcounter > inflater > refresh
                MainActivity.cardcounter = 0;
                if (!refresh){
                refreshFragment();
                    refresh = true;
                }
                break;
            case 1:                         // V title  Vcontent    V img
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Facts", "string a", R.drawable.ic_birthdays,reporticon));
                //workaround
                MainActivity.cardcounter = 1;
                if (!refresh){
                    refreshFragment();
                    refresh = true;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("History", "string a", R.drawable.ic_history,reporticon));
                //workaround
                MainActivity.cardcounter = 2;
                if (!refresh){
                    refreshFragment();
                    refresh = true;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Birthday", "string a", R.drawable.ic_lifehacks,reporticon));
            //workaround
            MainActivity.cardcounter = 3;
            if (!refresh){
                refreshFragment();
                refresh = true;
            }
            break;
            case 4:
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Lifehacks", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                //workaround
                MainActivity.cardcounter = 4;
                if (!refresh){
                    refreshFragment();
                    refresh = true;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Quotes", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                //workaround
                MainActivity.cardcounter = 5;
                if (!refresh){
                    refreshFragment();
                    refresh = true;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                CardEntry.add(new CardItem("Favorites", "string a", R.drawable.ic_facts,reporticon));
                //workaround
                MainActivity.cardcounter = 6;
                if (!refresh){
                    refreshFragment();
                    refresh = true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return CardEntry;
    }


    public List<CardItem> getCardEntry() {
        return CardEntry;
    }
    // end recycler


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment * iets aangepast, return onderaan voor recycler drawer
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);
            // pak het id van de recycler uit xml
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerCardList);
            // haal de data  op uit de return/switch hier boven
            //
            mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RVAdapter(getCardData(MainActivity.cardcounter));
            //
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
            // zet hem als dit op deze activity
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
              return layout;
    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
    package info.androidhive.materialnavbar.ViewAdapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.materialnavbar.Activity.DownloadImageTask;
import info.androidhive.materialnavbar.Animations;
import info.androidhive.materialnavbar.CardItem;
import info.androidhive.materialnavbar.R;

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {


    // Recycler View Adapter
    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView personName;
        TextView personAge;
        ImageView personPhoto;
        ImageButton FavBut;
        ImageButton ReportBut;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            personAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            personPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
            FavBut = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.FavBut);
            ReportBut = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ReportBut);

        }
    }

    List<CardItem> cardItems;

    public RVAdapter(List<CardItem> cardItems) {
        this.cardItems = cardItems;
    }


    public Object getCard(int position) {
        return cardItems.get(position);
    }

    public List<CardItem> getCardItems() {
        return cardItems;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.carditem, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }


    // de 'onCreate'
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        // vult het object/element met
        personViewHolder.personName.setText(cardItems.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.personAge.setText(cardItems.get(i).age);
        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(cardItems.get(i).photoId);
        //fav
        personViewHolder.FavBut.setImageResource(cardItems.get(i).favId);
        //report
        personViewHolder.ReportBut.setImageResource(cardItems.get(i).reportId);

        //zet animation op dit object/element
        Animations.animateScatter(personViewHolder, true);


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardItems.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the View's ID? I guess you are getting the same ID because RecyclerView reuses Views.

Comment: can you post Adapter & Fragment class ?

Comment: I've updated the problem aswell, so it is more specific now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a interface like this

```
public static interface ItemClickListener<T>{
    void onItemClick(T itemdata);
}
```

Create the feild in your Adapter and initialize this in constructor like this

```
ItemClickListener<CardItem> mItemClickListener;

public ClientsAdapter(ItemClickListener<CardItem> itemClickListener) {
    mItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

And in your bind

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
final CardItem item = mCardItems.get(i);
personViewHolder.FavBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        mItemClickListener.onItemClick(item);
    }

});
```

And in your fragment implement the ItemClickListener interface and pass it to the adapter